# Best way to consume auth0 authenticated REST API in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, gradle, auth0

I have to implement an authentication mechanism in the existing REST api client code which uses springboot, Specifically RestTemplate class. The server api uses auth0 authentication. I have a client id,secret and audience using which i need to generate an access token to make a call to the api. I also need to implement a mechanism to refresh the token after expiry. Does springboot provide inbuilt mechanism to manage this token? I looked up java development resources on auth0 and found [this client library](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-java). However, i don't want to add an extra library because of multiple reasons. I would rather do custom implementation or use inbuilt springboot mechanism.

Comment: This is just _OAuth2_, and Spring Security does have client libraries for it. That said, "adding an extra library" is _just the way things are done_ and there's no reason to reinvent the code yourself.

Comment: Agreed. Not trying to reinvent it but this is a small addition i am doing and adding a new library will require me to go through multiple admin process(stupid corporate policy). Thanks i will checkout Spring Security .